# YouTube keyboard shortcut to like or dislike (thumbs-up or thumbs-down)?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

I use YouTube keyboard shortcuts <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>, and <kbd>1–0</kbd>. Is there a similar key to toggle the like and dislike buttons (thumbs-up or thumbs-down buttons)?

Comment: Not an official one: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en - But this Chrome extension works: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-like-dislike-shor/fdkpkpelkkdkjhpacficichkfifijipc?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

If you install **[this user script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34049-youtube-like-dislike-video-and-skip-ad-keyboard-shortcuts)**, you will be able to like and dislike videos with keyboard shortcuts
 **<kbd>`[`</kbd>** and **<kbd>`]`</kbd>** (and as bonus you can even skip the ad with **<kbd>`s`</kbd>** key)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Youtube like/dislike video and skip ad keyboard shortcuts
// @namespace   nerevar009
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/*
// @description Adds keyboard shortcuts [ and ] for liking and disliking videos, and s for skipping pre-video and banner ads.
// @version     1.1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var onvideopage, skipad, skipbannerad, videoinfo, buttons, like, dislike, tag;

function findButtons() {
if(!/^\/watch/.test(location.pathname)) {
onvideopage = false;
return;
}
onvideopage = true;

skipad = document.getElementsByClassName("videoAdUiSkipButton");
if(skipad.length == 1)
skipad = skipad[0];
else skipad = null;

skipbannerad = document.getElementsByClassName("close-padding");
if(skipbannerad.length == 1)
skipbannerad = skipbannerad[0];
else skipbannerad = null;

videoinfo = document.getElementsByTagName("ytd-menu-renderer");
if(videoinfo.length >= 1) {
buttons = videoinfo[0].getElementsByTagName("button");
like = buttons[0];
dislike = buttons[1];
}
else {
like = null;
dislike = null;
}
}

findButtons();
var observer = new MutationObserver(findButtons);
observer.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true, subtree: true});

// add keybindings
addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
if(!onvideopage)
return;

if(e.target.getAttribute("contenteditable") == "true")
return;

tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
if(tag == "input" || tag == "textarea")
return;

if(e.code == "BracketLeft" && like)
like.click();
else if(e.code == "BracketRight" && dislike)
dislike.click();
else if(e.code == "KeyS") {
if(skipad)
skipad.click();
else if(skipbannerad)
skipbannerad.click();
}
});
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>`Tab`</kbd> key 13 times and then <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.

If there are tags, you will have to press tab to skip over each tag as well.
You can also hold tab to speed it up, and you can go back with <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`Tab`</kbd>.

Comment: For me was needed 12 times, thx anyway, not the best method, but is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment on answers due to insufficient reputation, so: for the script in the main answer to work I had to change this line:

```
  if(!/^/watch/.test(location.pathname)) {
```

to this:

```
  if(!/^\/watch/.test(location.pathname)) {
```

I believe it is the text field formatting screwing up the escapes. E.g. when I just tried to post \ followed by / it displayed only as /, which is probably what happened in the answer above as well.